# Remove prefix after match before forwarding request to service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have this base url `api.example.com`

So, `ingress-nginx` will get the request for `api.example.com` and it should do follow things.

Forward `api.example.com/customer` to `customer-srv`

It doesn't work, it forwards whole mtach to customer-srv i.e. `/customer/requested_url`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.example.in
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /customer/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: customer-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I tried using rewrite annotation but that doesn't work either however this worked but this is not I want to achieve.

```
    paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: customer-srv
            port:
              number: 3000
```

For example,

`api.example.com/customer` should go to `http://localhost:3000` not `http://localhost:3000/customer`

Comment: "I tried using rewrite annotation but that doesn't work" - What is the issue with it? What does not work?

Comment: I tried rewriting api.example.com/customer to  `/` now this goes to the default handler  after re-matching  all the routes while this should to customer-srv

Comment: After you used `rewrite-target: /$1` with `path: /customer/?(.*)`, what did you see vs what did you expect to see? Because imo it should work when you use rewrite-target like this.

Comment: But there may be some issues when you are rewriting paths and application is not aware of that. But it all depends an the actual application and I cannot help you without knowing how the application works.

Comment: Many web applications allow you to set so called `base path` or `root path` which adds prefix to all paths generated by the website. e.g. when you request a website on / you get html data with paths to images, js scripts etc. Imagine you rewrite some path /website to /, and the website sees / and serves you the html with reference to images. Let's say the html looks like: `<img src="/someimage.jpg">`.

Comment: now the browser tries to pull the image requesting `/someimage.jpg` and ingress has no ides where to forward this request. When using basepath like e.g. `/website`, web server can be aware the it is behind proxy and the paths are being rewriten so it adds /website prefix to all links. e.g. it will genereate html: `<img src="/website/someimage.jpg">`. Now when the ingress rewrites path from /website to /, all will work as expected.

Comment: Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: @Matt Are you familiar with reverse proxy or proxy_pass directive in nginx. This is ingress nginx file. All I want is when nginx gets request with prefix `/customer` it should handover request to `customer-srv` but it should remove the prefix `/customer`.
I tried rewrite annotation, but then it throws not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the yaml I used:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.example.in
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /customer/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: customer-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

For test purpouses I created an echo server:

```
kubectl run --image mendhak/http-https-echo customer
```

And then a service:

```
kubectl expose po customer --name customer-srv --port 3000 --target-port 80
```

I checked igress ip:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                  CLASS    HOSTS               ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
ingress-service       <none>   api.example.in      192.168.39.254   80      3m43s
```

And I did a curl to check it:

```
curl 192.168.39.254/customer/asd -H "Host: api.example.in"           
{
  "path": "/asd",
  "headers": {
    "host": "api.example.in",

...
}
```

Notice that the echo server echoed back a path that it received, and sice it received a path that got rewritten from `/customer/asd` to `/asd` it shows this exectly path (/asd).

So as you see this does work.